# C++ Pointers, Text Files and Dynamic Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, file, pointers, dynamic

Im new to C++ and I have decided to do a little car project as something to do.

Basically I want to store Cars in a text file and then display them, which I have done. The problem is that I want the array of cars to be 30 so when I run the program it prints random numbers to fill up the spare spaces in the array.

How do I go about fixing this. Someone said something about a pointer and have a number at the top of the text file so it can work out how many cars there are. Also someone mentioned a Dynamic Array.

Please help. Been stuck on this for a week now.

Comment: Post some code showing the problem.

Comment: You've got to understand that when people give you suggestions often either they don't understand the problem, or you don't understand the advice. Since you've been stuck a whole week, take a minute or two to show us the code you've written. It will improve understanding all round.

Comment: Also, don't think there is some piece of magic called 'pointers' or 'dynamic arrays' that will solve your problem. You already have the tools to do this. The most important thing is to better understand the tools you have.

Answer (score 2):

In `C++` prefer to use

```
std::vector<Car> myCars
```

to hold a number of `Car` instances.

You then just

```
myCars.push_back(aCarIGotFromAFile)
```

and it will grow as needed.

Answer (score 0):

**"Basically I want to store Cars in a text file and then display them, which I have done"**

nice you have done 90% of the project!.

**"cars to be 30 so when I run the program it prints random numbers to fill up the spare spaces in the array"** is the problem.

**"Someone said something about a pointer"** good someone showed you to a dangerous but awesome path.

**"Also someone mentioned a Dynamic Array"** this too is a good suggestion.
lets put all this together

1) you said you store into the file some 30 cars. now what you do is store additional information in the file like for e.g Total number of cars, car manufacturer etc.

now when your done with that you have to retrieve information and store them in the array.

you might be reading from the file using ifstream (or istream) or equivalent. now what you do is  create a **Container** to hold the values.

```
ifstream iflie("cars.txt");
ifile >> TotalCars;
```

in C++ the favourite container(use std namespace) is :

```
template < class T, class AllocationClass = allocator<T> > 
class vector
```

this is a template class where you can declare an object as so

```
std::vector<std::string> cars(TotalCars); /*this should be 30*/
```

now as you deal with arrays same thing applies to vectors. use `[]` like so `cars[i]`. now when you have more cars use cars.push_back(element). and your good to go.